# Is it possible to enforce that a Timestamp field is only updated if it is on the same day as the current date?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a booking app where the user can change the time of their booking, but only if the  new time is on the same day as the current day that they have booked. Is it technically possible to enforce this on firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the date in the document against the [`request.time` variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#time), which is the timestamp on the server. Assuming that the field in your document is a Firestore [`Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Timestamp), you can compare `year` and `dayOfYear` properties of the two timestamps. If they're both the same, the value in the field is the current day.